# Shell Script for formatted output

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ksh, shell-builtin

```
06/26/2017 23:40:40       CAUAJM_I_10082 [aspsun14 connected for IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL 55443.15215291.1]
06/26/2017 23:40:40       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14
06/26/2017 23:40:42       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: RUNNING         JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14
06/26/2017 23:49:19       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14        EXITCODE:  0
06/27/2017 23:40:23       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14
06/27/2017 23:40:24       CAUAJM_I_10082 [aspsun14 connected for IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL 55443.15236942.1]
06/27/2017 23:40:25       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: RUNNING         JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14
06/27/2017 23:48:19       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14        EXITCODE:  0
06/28/2017 23:41:36       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: STARTING        JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14
06/28/2017 23:41:37       CAUAJM_I_10082 [aspsun14 connected for IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL 55443.15258301.1]
06/28/2017 23:41:38       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: RUNNING         JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14
06/28/2017 23:48:47       CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS    STATUS: SUCCESS         JOB: IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL MACHINE: aspsun14        EXITCODE:  0
```

I have a file having above content, I want the output like, job name then start time then End time

```
IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL 06/26/2017 23:40:40 06/26/2017 23:49:19
IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL 06/27/2017 23:40:23 06/27/2017 23:48:19
IOALPPRXXBD_ALPGLGENFAALL 06/28/2017 23:41:36 06/28/2017 23:48:47
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk is very convenient for these things.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$5 == "CHANGE_STATUS" && $7 == "STARTING" {
    start[$9] = $1 " " $2
}

$5 == "CHANGE_STATUS" && $7 == "SUCCESS" {
    print $9,start[$9],$1,$2
}
```

$n is the n-th column. I just store the beginning date and print everything once I found the end date of the job. 
(Save the code in an executable file and call it by passing the input file as argument.)
`./script input.txt`

If you absolutely need to embed it in a Bash script, just do something like:

```
awk '
    $5 == "CHANGE_STATUS" && $7 == "STARTING" {
        start[$9] = $1 " " $2
    }

    $5 == "CHANGE_STATUS" && $7 == "SUCCESS" {
        print $9,start[$9],$1,$2
    }
' input_file_or_whatever
```

but be careful with what you do with single quotes in the Awk script itself. It might get a little tricky.